# Haskell - parsing error on input '=' ghc

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement the fibonacci function in haskell just to try the language out, but I am already stuck at just compiling my program. I have the following code:

```
main = do
    fib :: (Num a) => a -> a
    fib 0 = 0
    fib 1 = 1
    fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 3)
    fib 348
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong. This is the output of ghc while compiling it with `ghc --make fib.hs`

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main           ( fib.hs, fib.o )
fib.hs:3:15: parse error on input `=´
```

In case this is relevant, I am using windows.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that it's telling you in the error message where the error is - knowing the '=' at 3:15 (line 3 character 15) is the offending one is often highly useful.

Answer (score 6):

`fib 0 = 0` etc are not "actions" that can be sequenced in `do`. Define `fib` outside `main` (or in `where`, or in `let ... in`), then decide what you want to do with it. `fib 348` just calculates a number; but you need an `IO` result for `main`.

I don't have an interpreter nearby, but something like this:

```
main = do
  putStrLn $ show $ fib 348
  where
    fib 0 = 0
    fib 1 = 1
    fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 3)
```

or this:

```
fib :: (Num a) => a -> a
fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 3)

main = do
  putStrLn (show (fib 348))
```

**EDIT**: Regarding the comment below and "stack size too small": There is a typo in your code, which I blindly copied. Fibonacci is `fib x = fib (x - 1) + fib (x - 2)`; you have `fib (x - 3)` in your code. This means that when `fib 2` is reached, it will be evaluated as `fib 1 + fib (-1)`. Now, when you evaluate `fib (-1)`, that's an infinite loop, since you "dropped off the bottom" and will just continue to go deeper and deeper. And stacks are typically not infinite.

Also be aware that calculating a big Fibonacci number in this way (without memoisation) is very, very, *very* slow.

Comment: thank you! that at least executes. however, it is saying that the stack size is too small. I guess this has to do something with this being a recursive function? I don't understand why this would occur though

Comment: @nils8950 It should be noted that even with the correct `fib` definition, computing `fib 348` would take an awful lot of time using that algorithm.